# Changing text font color and views

Tags: beamerposter, sharelatex

```
    %==============================================================================
%== template for LATEX poster =================================================
%==============================================================================
%
%--A0 beamer slide-------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,
            scale=1.25         % font scale factor
           ]{beamerposter}

\geometry{
  hmargin=2.5cm, % little modification of margins
}

%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\linespread{1.15}
%
%==The poster style============================================================
\usetheme{sharelatex}

%==Title, date and authors of the poster=======================================
\title
[Super Conference, 1 - 10 July 2013, New York, USA] % Conference
{ % Poster title
 {\Large TECHKIDS }
}

\author{ % Authors
Author One\inst{1}, Author Two\inst{2}, Author Three\inst{2,3}
}
\institute
[Very Large University] % General University
{
\inst{1} Very Large University, Neverland\\[0.3ex]
\inst{2} Other University, Neverland\\[0.3ex]
\inst{3} Yet Another University, Neverland
}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{somerights}} 
\begin{frame}[t]
%==============================================================================
\begin{multicols}{3}
%==============================================================================
%==The poster content==========================================================
%==============================================================================

\section{Introduction}

"there's no agony than bearing an untold story inside you"- maya angelou. is this the feeling of your heart? then, stop being a story bearer, instead be a storyteller! hey, hey, hey! do not forget your poems and other stuffs!


\structure{Your text with scientific results or something...} $\hat H \Psi = E \Psi$  
Your text with scientific results or something... 


\begin{equation}
H = \sum_{i=1}^{N} h_{D}(i) + \sum_{j>i=1}^{N} C_{ij}
\end{equation}

Your text with scientific results or something... 


In Ref.~\cite{ref1}...
In Refs.~\cite{ref1,ref2}...
On webpage~\cite{web}...


\section{Result and discussions}

Your text with scientific results or something... 


\vskip1ex
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{This is a table with scientific results.}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee\\
aaaa & bbbb & cccc & dddd & eeee\\
aaaaa & bbbbb & ccccc & ddddd & eeeee\\
aaaaaa & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd & eeeeee\\
1.000 & 2.000 & 3.000 & 4.000 & 5.000\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\vskip2ex

Your text with scientific results or something... 


\subsection{SubSection}

Your text with scientific results or something... 



\vskip1ex
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.99\columnwidth]{logo.png}
\caption{This is a picture with scientific results.}
\end{figure}
\vskip2ex

Your text with scientific results or something... 



\subsection{SubSection, a very very very very very very long title}

Your text with scientific results or something... 


\section{Contact Details}
 fabinahian@gmail.com  \\  www.facebook.com/techkidsbd \\  www.techworldbd.com

%--End of references-----------------------------------------------------------

\end{multicols}

%==============================================================================
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the above latex poster The text is not that visible due to the background image.
[image]

> How color how how to make these text more visible?
>   How can I enlarge the Headline with different color??

Comment: Where can we find `sharelatex` theme?

Comment: I lost it :( Can you tell me that how can i Enlarge the heading and chae the color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So even without much information, I try to to be psychic.

Let us assume, you refer to the `sharelatex` theme which you can find here: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fe1a8134a287a85245b503

Than you can change the title size and its colour by alterning line 114 in `beamerthemesharelatex.sty`

Concerning the readability: how about using an image in lighter colours to enhance the readability?
[image]